# Add up price in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to add up the price in my foreach loop to give me an overall total. I am struggling as I can only get the first value:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product) {
    $name = $product['name'];
    $id = $product['id'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $img = $product['img'];
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $description = $product['description'];

    echo '<a href="single_product.php?product_id=' . $product['id'] . '">';
    echo "<img src='$img'><br />";
    echo "Product: $name<br />";
    echo "Price: $price | ID: $id<br />";
    echo "$description";
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<br /><br />';

    $sum += $price;

}
    echo $price;
```

I have probably gone about this the wrong way but looking online keep telling me the same approach but I am confused:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo `$sum` instead of `$price` outside of loop, as you are storing total in `$sum`

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product) {
    ...
    $price = $product['price'];
    ...
    $sum += $price;
}
echo $sum; // echo $sum over here
```

Comment: Oh my I was so close!